# How do run multiple commands in a Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I've used the terminal to commit changes and push to my Github repo for quite a while. I just recently started using Sass through terminal too.

However I'm unsure the best way to use terminal with the two together, because I constantly find myself having to exit and restart to perform different tasks.

I'm looking into lots of other tools that I might like to use and I'm concerned if any more of them require terminal I will struggle.

For example, I've started up a project and pulled from my repo:

```
cd Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project
git pull origin master
```

Now I want to start watching a file in Sass

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

This now puts terminal into `ruby` as it runs Sass.

Now I want to commit something. But I'm in ruby so what do I do?

At present, I just exit terminal and `cd` back to the dir but I know there must be a quicker way.

Comment: `Cmd+N` will open an additional Terminal....

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git or Sass.

Answer (score -1):

On OS X cmd+T should open up a new tab in the terminal window where you can continue to work on your 'other' task. Use cmd + shift + [  to switch between tabs.